# How to keep pivot header text in the center of the screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I want to keep the header of the pivot Items in the center of the screen, but not able to do so, Always the pivot title and the pivot header appears in the left of the screen.
Is there any idea to customize the pivot items, either by XAML or by Code??

```
<controls:Pivot Title="Select a Game" FontSize="51" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="&#x2022;"  FontSize="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
```

Note: I want to display the unicode circle bullets ("•") in the center of the screen, either in the top of the screen or on bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the pivot item titles, add your custom centered text-block in the content of `PivotItem`. When a user taps on the next header / makes a swipe gesture, you can use `SelectedIndex` property to navigate to different pivot items.